# How can I draw a circle using tikz : \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm] plot[smooth,domain=0:2] (\x, {sqrt(1-(x-1)^2)});

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can I draw a circle using this code in tikz :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background

\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}  % order of layers (main = standard layer)

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}



\begin{document}






\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=0:2] (\x, {sqrt(1-(x-1)^2)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Erh, that is half a circle. What exactly are your goal?

It is a lot easier to plot functions in `pgfplots` than in basic `tikz`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis equal
    ]
    \addplot [smooth,domain=0:2,samples=101] {sqrt(1-(\x-1)^2)};
    \addplot [smooth,domain=0:2,samples=101] {-sqrt(1-(\x-1)^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the circle probably to be smooth and may thus want to draw the circle in one go. This can be achieved by using a function that runs from 0 to 2 and then back,

```
(\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x)
```

Then you need to decide whether you are in the upper or lower branch with `sign(2-\x)`, so that the plot command becomes

```
  \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm] 
    plot[smooth cycle,domain=0:4,samples=101] 
  ({(\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x)}, {sign(2-\x)*sqrt(1-((\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x)-1)^2)});
```

which is much more efforts than a standard circle path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text width=2.5cm,align=center}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=A]
  \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm] 
    plot[smooth cycle,domain=0:4,samples=101] 
  ({(\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x)}, {sign(2-\x)*sqrt(1-((\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x)-1)^2)});
 \end{scope}
 \path (A.south) node[below] {engineering a function};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,local bounding box=B,
    declare function={xcheat(\x)=(\x<2 ? \x : 4-\x);}]
  \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm] 
    plot[smooth cycle,domain=0:4,samples=101] 
  ({xcheat(\x)}, {sign(2-\x)*sqrt(1-(xcheat(\x)-1)^2)});
 \end{scope}
 \path (B.south) node[below] {engineering and declaring a function};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,local bounding box=C]
  \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm] (1,0) circle[radius=1cm];
 \end{scope}
 \path (C.south) node[below] {use normal circle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]